# VHDL Synthesize Block Ram with Multiple Outputs

Tags: vhdl, fpga

```
if rising_edge(CLK_100Mhz) then
  if w_ram = '1' then
    for X in 0 to 6 loop
        for Y in 0 to 6 loop
            DataO(X)(Y)(0) <= Memory(X)(Y)(Address);
            DataO(X)(Y)(1) <= Memory(X)(Y)(Address+1);
            DataO(X)(Y)(2) <= Memory(X)(Y)(Address+2);
            DataO(X)(Y)(3) <= Memory(X)(Y)(Address+3);
            Memory(X)(Y)(Address) <= DataI(X)(Y)(0);
        end loop;
    end loop;
  w_ram <= '0';
end if;
end if;
```

I need to use block ram for my data intensive project. Would this work as a 1 input, 4 output block for every given X,Y or would this create 4 blocks for every given X,Y? Also would this even work? I'm using a Xilinx Zynq-7000 FPGA.

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible to rewrite your code so it needs only one RAM. Depending on the sizes it can still need multiple BlockRAMs. Can you add the used datatypes for Address, DataI, DataO and Memory? You are accessing the memory at consecutive addresses so it's one memory line that is to be split into 4 words. Writing to the memory can be done by using byte enables.

Comment: Something of the sort can be made to work, but depending on the width of Data, accessing 196 memory locations in a single clock cycle may take a lot of BlockRams.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the Xilinx synthesis tool to infer multiple asymmetric block RAMs.  Xilinx has sample code to infer one RAM, which can be found at

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_2/xst_v6s6.pdf

The write port is 8 bits wide and 256 deep and the read port is 32 bits wide and 64 deep.  Here's the code from the above link:

```
-- Asymmetric port RAM
-- Port A is 256x8-bit write-only
-- Port B is 64x32-bit read-only
--
-- Download: ftp://ftp.xilinx.com/pub/documentation/misc/xstug_examples.zip
-- File: HDL_Coding_Techniques/rams/asymmetric_ram_1a.vhd
--
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity asymmetric_ram_1a is
generic (
    WIDTHA      : integer := 8;
    SIZEA       : integer := 256;
    ADDRWIDTHA  : integer := 8;
    WIDTHB      : integer := 32;
    SIZEB       : integer := 64;
    ADDRWIDTHB  : integer := 6
);
port (
    clkA    : in    std_logic;
    clkB    : in    std_logic;
    weA     : in    std_logic;
    enA     : in    std_logic;
    enB     : in    std_logic;
    addrA   : in    std_logic_vector(ADDRWIDTHA-1 downto 0);
    addrB   : in    std_logic_vector(ADDRWIDTHB-1 downto 0);
    diA     : in    std_logic_vector(WIDTHA-1 downto 0);
    doB     :   out std_logic_vector(WIDTHB-1 downto 0)
);
end asymmetric_ram_1a;

architecture behavioral of asymmetric_ram_1a is

function max(L, R: INTEGER) return INTEGER is
begin
    if L > R then
        return L;
    else
        return R;
    end if;
end;

function min(L, R: INTEGER) return INTEGER is
begin
    if L < R then
        return L;
    else
        return R;
    end if;
end;

constant minWIDTH : integer := min(WIDTHA,WIDTHB);
constant maxWIDTH : integer := max(WIDTHA,WIDTHB);
constant maxSIZE  : integer := max(SIZEA,SIZEB);
constant RATIO    : integer := maxWIDTH / minWIDTH;

type ramType is array (0 to maxSIZE-1) of std_logic_vector(minWIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal ram : ramType := (others => (others => '0'));
signal readB : std_logic_vector(WIDTHB-1 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal regB : std_logic_vector(WIDTHB-1 downto 0):= (others => '0');

begin
process (clkA)
begin
    if rising_edge(clkA) then
        if enA = '1' then
            if weA = '1' then
                ram(conv_integer(addrA)) <= diA;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

process (clkB)
begin
    if rising_edge(clkB) then
        if enB = '1' then
            readB(minWIDTH-1 downto 0)
            <= ram(conv_integer(addrB&conv_std_logic_vector(0,2)));
            readB(2*minWIDTH-1 downto minWIDTH)
            <= ram(conv_integer(addrB&conv_std_logic_vector(1,2)));
            readB(3*minWIDTH-1 downto 2*minWIDTH)
            <= ram(conv_integer(addrB&conv_std_logic_vector(2,2)));
            readB(4*minWIDTH-1 downto 3*minWIDTH)
            <= ram(conv_integer(addrB&conv_std_logic_vector(3,2)));
        end if;
    regB <= readB;
    end if;
end process;

doB <= regB;

end behavioral;
```

Here's an excerpt the synthesis report confirming that XST infers an asymmetric memory.

```
Synthesizing (advanced) Unit <asymmetric_ram_1a>.
INFO:Xst:3226 - The RAM <Mram_ram> will be implemented as a BLOCK RAM, absorbing the following register(s): <readB> <regB>
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    | ram_type           | Block                               |          |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Port A                                                              |
    |     aspect ratio   | 256-word x 8-bit                    |          |
    |     mode           | write-first                         |          |
    |     clkA           | connected to signal <clkA>          | rise     |
    |     weA            | connected to signal <weA_0>         | high     |
    |     addrA          | connected to signal <addrA>         |          |
    |     diA            | connected to signal <diA>           |          |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    | optimization       | speed                               |          |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Port B                                                              |
    |     aspect ratio   | 64-word x 32-bit                    |          |
    |     mode           | write-first                         |          |
    |     clkB           | connected to signal <clkB>          | rise     |
    |     enB            | connected to signal <enB>           | high     |
    |     addrB          | connected to signal <addrB>         |          |
    |     doB            | connected to signal <doB>           |          |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    | optimization       | speed                               |          |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
Unit <asymmetric_ram_1a> synthesized (advanced).

=========================================================================
Advanced HDL Synthesis Report

Macro Statistics
# RAMs                                                 : 1
 256x8:64x32-bit dual-port block RAM                   : 1
```

Note, port B is read-only despite what the synthesis report says.